# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.keras.applications'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to import

```py
import tensorflow.python.keras.applications
```

but it gives the bellow error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.keras.applications'
```

my TensorFlow version is 2.8.0 and Keras version is 2.8.0

Comment: is it `tensorflow.keras.applications`?

Comment: @Chris_Rands I am using Object Detection on Tensorflow and I am running a script that makes sure all modules are installed and it uses ``import tensorflow.python.keras.applications``

Comment: I am using Colab and this error message popped up from nowhere.  Didn't have this problem previously.

Answer (score 8):

Try using `import keras.applications` instead of `import tensorflow.python.keras.applications`

Answer (score 3):

my solution was downgrade tensorflow to 2.7

!pip uninstall tensorflow
!pip install tensorflow==2.7

Comment: I am using colab and it does not recommend downgrade tensorflow.  what a mess!!!

Answer (score 2):

No need to downgrade or uninstall tensorflow. The resolution of this error resides in resnet_v1.py file i changed the foll line:

- `from tensorflow.python.keras.applications import resnet`

to

- `from tensorflow.keras.applications import resnet`

and it got resolved because tensorflow.python is deprecated long time ago.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to fix the problem by uninstalling TensorFlow and installing it back.

```
pip uninstall tensorflow
pip install tensorflow
```